# Qt Widget for using with following purposes? (text editor, links)

Tags: qt, widget, text-editor, hyperlink

**Please,**
recommend Widget for using with following purposes:

- Edit text In the widget, as in a text editor
- Links in the text
- Images in the text (desirable)

Editing features:

- Editable Links: straight from the widget to change the title of links.
- Pressing "Enter" on link - go to the link target

Of course, the complete widget does exists.
What to use as a basis.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`QTextEdit`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtextedit.html) .